# Finding the highest/max in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Noob learning Ruby over here. I feel like the answer will be super obvious to someone, as soon as they see it. Thanks for reading.

I have a hash. I want to take the highest number value from the Hash, and then output the key/name of the the highest value.  Right now it outputs both, and I'm not sure why. If anyone would be able to explain, the error, and point me in the right direction, would be very appreciated.

```
donation = {
    "José" => 1000,
    "Mike" => 50
}

donation.each do |name, money|
    puts "#{name} $#{money}"
end
```

that part's fine, but down here, I'm wanting to get ther highest value number, and output the name.

```
big_bux = donation.max_by { |name, money| money.to_i }

big_bux.select do |name, money|
    puts "#{name} gave the most."
end
```

it outputs

> José gave the most.

> 1000 gave the most.

It was part of some other homework, which I seemed to have got, but not this part.
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over a hash enumerable it converts each key-value pair into an array (behaves like a tuple). So when you do `{ foo: 1 }.max_by.first` you get `[:foo, 1]`. And when you do `donation.max_by { |name, money| money.to_i }` you end up with `["José", 1000]`.

Then `select`  is iterating over each item in `big_bux` and returning only results where the block evaluates to a truthy value. But since you're actually just calling `puts …` in the block you're going to get every item in `big_bux` written to the output.

If you want to have the name and donation amount after doing `max_by`, you can do this:

```rb
name, donationAmount = donation.max_by { |name, money| money.to_i }

puts "#{name} is a big spender, donating $#{donationAmount}!"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, coreyward! I really appreciate that. And the solution; I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that! Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

```
donation = {
    "José" => 1000,
    "Mike" => 50
}
```

```
donation.max_by(&:last).first
  #=> "José"
```

See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by). The steps are as follows.

```
arr = donation.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["José", 1000]
```

which is shorthand for

```
arr = donation.max_by { |k,v| v }
  #=> ["José", 1000]
```

Then

```
arr.first
  #=> "José"
```